# Best practice when documenting WPF projects

Tags: c#, wpf, documentation

I'm currently documenting my application that consists of various User Controls. Now I'm wondering how the best practice is when documenting. Do you document both classes in a user control? Or only the code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the best practice is to follow MVVM pattern in WPF projects. I you follow it, you will not have the code-behind at all. So there will be only one place to document.

But I understand that it is not always the case. So my general advice is: keep the documentation as close to the logic that it documents as possible. And put it where the person who is going to read it expects it to see. If it is a general description of a class that most likely will be viewed in the intellisense, then put it on the code-behind class. if it is a description of a user interface, then put in the XAML file.

Comment: Having no code behind at all is nearly impossible if you have some interractive interface using the full power of WPF.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to document the XAML only where it makes sense, like describing what a certain set of styles do or how a block of markup works.  I tend to keep the majority of the comments in the code behind since they are normally easier to read and follow.  Plus I tend to go to the code behind to try and understand what the code does first instead of jumping into reading the XAML.